# Expo Go can't connect with project

Tags: expo, qr-code

I wanted to test react native app on expo go. I have downloaded expo go app, run expo start in VSC, and once scanned QR code using expo go I get such log.
Looks like there is issue with network connection...
Anybody know how to fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

expo Lan not working in windows

-- show my personal experience same problem faced but I resolve this problem some steps follow as

*** imp ***

1. run administration cmd.
2. (optional) use a tunnel.
3. the last one used for my side -- first go to wifi network but the same network used in phone or window.

Properties.
then
private click, not public.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when I first started with Expo.

One other thing you can try to see if it's jut a firewall rule blocking you is to go into your firewall and TEMPORARILY turn it off to see. For example, in Windows Defender Firewall, I can go to "Private Networks" and see my WiFi is categorized there and I can then select "Turns Windows Firewall On/Off" and turn it off for Private Networks.

In my case, this IS what the problem was and after I turned off the firewall, Expo loaded the app up in a jiffy.

You do NOT want to leave your firewall off just for working with expo, so the best solution is add a rule to just allow this traffic through.

For me (using Windows), I had to go into Advanced Settings and create a new Inbound Rule for Expo to allow the expo ports (i.e. 19000+) to remain open so I can test/work with my firewall on.

Answer (score 3):

this depends on your network - you may need to use the "tunnel" connection type depending on your wifi network configuration.

see the [expo new app tutorial](https://docs.expo.io/get-started/create-a-new-app/), under the "Is the app not loading on your device?" heading for more information (inlined below at the time of writing for your convenience):

> First, make sure that you are on the same wifi network on your computer and your device.
>
> If it still doesn't work, it may be due to the router configuration — this is common for public networks. You can work around this by choosing the "Tunnel" connection type in Expo Dev Tools, then scanning the QR code again.
>
> Using the "Tunnel" connection type will make app reloads considerably slower than on "LAN" or "Local", so it's best to avoid tunnel when possible. You may want to install a simulator/emulator to speed up development if "Tunnel" is required for accessing your machine from another device on your network.

Comment: phone and laptop are under same wifi network... thanks for the link, will go through it

Answer (score 1):

GO with tunnel its slower than LAN AND LOCAL but its work